# handling parameters and regex in string.Format

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using a query in providing parameters through `string.Format (query, id, batch)` I am also using `REGEXP_LIKE(A.NI,'^\d{13}$')` to restrict selection to only 13 digits found in NI column, due to curly braces as they fit parameters in query in string.Format(), **my regex {13}** is also being considered as parameter here and getting an exception of

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

How do handle this issue;
my query look like this;

```
SELECT B.ID,
       B.NI,
       B.NT,
       {1},
       B.MB, 
       SYSDATE 
  FROM (SELECT A.* 
          FROM core_table A 
         WHERE A.batch_id = {0} AND 
               (REGEXP_LIKE(A.NI,'^\d{13}$') OR 
                REGEXP_LIKE(A.NT,'^\d{7}$') OR 
                REGEXP_LIKE(A.MB,'^\d{11}$'))) B 
 WHERE B.BAT_ID = {0} AND 
       B.IS_DELETED = 0;
```

Comment: Don't do this - use a parameterized query and bind parameters. This opens you up to SQL injection attacks like `id = "(SELECT password_hash FROM security_table WHERE id = 123)"` and then `string.Format( query, id, batch )` will return the password_hash and not the value you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `string.Format` to fill the value {0} and {1}.

This will raise an exception because your string contains {13}, {7}, {11} and .NET thinks they are the placeholders like {0}, {1}.

You should fix your string by double `{{` and `}}`. Look at the code worked:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/TG8Wa7

```
string query = @"SELECT B.ID,B.NI,B.NT,{1},B.MB, SYSDATE FROM (SELECT A.*from core_table A where A.batch_id={0} AND (REGEXP_LIKE(A.NI,'^\d{{13}}$') OR REGEXP_LIKE(A.NT,'^\d{{7}}$') OR REGEXP_LIKE(A.MB,'^\d{{11}}$'))) B where B.BAT_ID={0} AND B.IS_DELETED=0;";
string.Format(query, "1","2");
```

Comment: did this, not working (actually checked this directly on query editor of oracle)